# Get all numbers containing only digit x and digit y

Tags: c#, algorithm

Sorry if question is bit confusing, I have scenario where I need two get all the numbers containing 5 and 2. Input would be starting number and end number, I need to find all number in between this two numbers which contains only digit 5 and digit 2.

For example

```
Input - starting number - 1 end number -30
Output - 2,5,22,25.
```

How to do this in C#?

EDIT :: As few fellow user asked what have i tried, Below is sample snippet i tried but i feel it is not a correct way to do. It will be costly

```
public static void main()
{
    int start = 1
    int end = 30

    for(int i = start; i<=end; i++)
    {
         if(CheckNumber(i))
         {
             Console.WriteLine(i);
         } 

     }
}

static bool CheckNumber(int num)
{
    int rem = 0;
    while(num != 0)
    {
         rem = num % 10;  
         if(rem != 2 || rem!=5)
             return false;
         num = num/10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: u need a loop, a way to make a number into a string and a way to look for digits in a string

Comment: You don't *need* a loop, or to use strings (think recursion).

Comment: @Yousaf I need a start, I tried doing something but it was all waste so finally I decided to put up here so atleast I might have some content to start with..

Comment: @ScottHunter - you are surely correct. The brute force way is simpler to understand but would fail with v large range (but is OK for 1-30)

Comment: @pm100: Depth wouldn't be deeper than # of digits, so I think it'd be fine.

Comment: @ScottHunter I mean for an obvious newb, trying to get a recursive alg going is not easy

Comment: @pm100: Not if she were raised right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using recursion and math:

```
void FiveTwo( int a, int b, int base ) {
    int n = base*10; // Number with all 2's & 5's and a 0 on the end
    if ( n+2<=b ) {
        FiveTwo(a,b,n+2);  // Find numbers bigger than n+2
        if ( a<=n+2 )
            Console.WriteLine( n+2 );  // Not too small to print
    }      
    if ( n+5<=b ) {
        FiveTwo(a,b,n+5);  // Find numbers bigger than n+5
        if ( a<=n+5 )
            Console.WriteLine( n+5 );  // Not too small to print
    } 
}
```

Call it like so:

```
FiveTwo( low, high, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 30);

            foreach (int n in numbers)
            {
                var m = Regex.Match(n.ToString(), "^[25]+$");

                if (m.Success)
                    Console.WriteLine(n);
            };

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's going to be pretty poky for a big range.

Comment: Maybe - but I am stupid. But I will try to get better asap.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void myFunc()
    {
        List<int> Result = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)

        {
                if (IsMyResult(i.ToString()) == true)
                    Result.Add(i);  
        }
    }

    private bool IsMyResult(string x)
    {
        string[] numbersToSearch = { "2", "5" }; // you can add here all the numbers you want to be inside the number you are searching

        foreach (char digit in x)
        {
            if (numbersToSearch.Contains(digit.ToString()))
            {
                // do nothing it containes desired digit
            }
            else
            {
                // return false its not the result
                return false;
            }
        }

        // if code reach here it must be true
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing *generator* which returns `IEnumerable<T>`; then you can easily create *arbitrary* queries with a help of *Linq*:

```
// In order to avoid int.MaxValue, long.MaxValue borders let's return strings 
private static IEnumerable<string> Generator(params int[] digits) {
  var vals = digits
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .ToArray();

  Queue<string> agenda = new Queue<string>(vals);

  while (true) {
    string value = agenda.Dequeue();

    yield return value;

    foreach (var v in vals)
      agenda.Enqueue(value + v);
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
// First 15 numbers contain 2 and 5 only
string report1 = string.Join(", ", Generator(2, 5).Take(15));

Console.WriteLine(report1);

// Numbers contain 2 and 5 only less than 30
string report2 = string.Join(", ", Generator(2, 5).TakeWhile(c => int.Parse(c) <= 30)); 

Console.WriteLine(report2);

// Numbers contain 2 and 5 only between 100 and 1000
string report3 = string.Join(", ", Generator(2, 5)
  .SkipWhile(c => int.Parse(c) < 100)
  .TakeWhile(c => int.Parse(c) < 1000));

Console.WriteLine(report3);
```

Output:

```
2, 5, 22, 25, 52, 55, 222, 225, 252, 255, 522, 525, 552, 555, 2222

2, 5, 22, 25

222, 225, 252, 255, 522, 525, 552, 555
```